# what is the best way to get my gmail contacts on my ipod touch contacts list

Tags: ipod-touch, contacts, gmail

i have a new ipod touch and i want to get my gmail contacts available on the ipod touch contacts.

what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iTunes offers this option in the sync panel out of the box, at least with an iPhone:  [image: Google contacts iPhone]

Answer (score 3):

I am using Google Sync for this, it sets my Google Account up as an Exchange server so emails, calendars (multiple) and contacts are synced over the air.

There is a walk through on how to set this up on the Google help pages for the sync feature.